# Keep Buttons from shifting depending on text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make it so that the `Buttons` are not shifted to the bottom depending on the content a `TextView` above it? 
If the `TextView` has a lot of text, the buttons are pushed down.
It may need to use `RelativeLayout`? Could you please explain how can i do it?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_company"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textColor="#002060"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        >
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_operations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_purchase"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text=" oper1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#001B51"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    ....... //4 more buttons

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_exit"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="  Exit"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#001B51"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Give the `TextView` a number of max lines. Otherwise, it's going to keep growing as it gets more text

Comment: I go on this way. thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, RelativeLayout would work better for this. Notice the new attributes added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbackground">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tv_company"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="#002060"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</TextView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_operations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_purchase"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:text=" oper1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:textColor="#001B51"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set their positions programmatically like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_operations);
button1.setLayoutParams(params);

//or set its position relative to another button:
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button1.getId());
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondBtn);
button2.setLayoutParams(params);

//or set its margins like this (left, top, right, bottom):
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(200, 600, 0, 0); //if it is possible don't use hard coded numbers, use parameters based on screen resolution instead
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thirdBtn);
button3.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, your `TextView` is going to grow as much as it needs. You can place restrictions on it such as using [maxLines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines)

```
<TextView
    android:maxLines="3"
    ... 
</TextView>
```

There is also [android:lines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lines)

If you wish, you can also use [android:ellipsize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) to show, for instance, at the end of the `TextView` that there is more text.

You can read [through the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to see which attributes are best for you.